# wordpress css image background image

Tags: css, wordpress, image, background-image

I am trying to get an image behind a video on a wordpress child theme of twenty sixteen.I tried using the following the file path.

```
background: url('../images/image.jpg’);
```

I have the image in a

```
.wp-block-video.aligncenter {
  text-align: center;
  border-style: solid;
```

but the image will not appear behind it 
 I modified the code but to no avail

```
background-image: {
    url('..images/('alliswell.ie_video_2018.jpg');
    width:100px;    
    height:100px; 
};
```

the website is alliswell.ie

Comment: Remove ( before 'alliswell

Comment: There are a few typos in your code. This should read: url('..images/('alliswell.ie_video_2018.jpg'); --> url('..images/alliswell.ie_video_2018.jpg');
Also, the quotes don't match in type here: background: url('../images/image.jpg’);
That said, do those images actually exist? Check the console for 404 errors, that will tell you if the path is wrong.

Comment: thnak you, i forgot the begining of the code, it had to be inserted into the div your code worked, i had to add curly brackets..wp-block-video.aligncenter{ background-image: url(alliswell.ie/wp-content/uploads/2018/09/…); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-size: cover; } – patrick yesterday

Answer (score 0):

Tag 'video' have attribut 'poster':
A URL for an image to be shown while the video is downloading. If this attribute isn't specified, nothing is displayed until the first frame is available, then the first frame is shown as the poster frame.

Comment: thnak you, i forgot the begining of the code, it had to be inserted into the div your code worked, i had to add curly brackets..wp-block-video.aligncenter{ background-image: url(alliswell.ie/wp-content/uploads/2018/09/…); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-size: cover; } – patrick yesterday

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below code :

```
.wp-block-video.aligncenter
    background-image: url(http://alliswell.ie/wp-content/uploads/2018/09/alliswell_ie_caring-forourwater_2018.jpg-e1536244962710.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

In `background-image` use complete url.  background-image: url(../images/images.jpg) unable to find the image path.

Comment: thnak you, i forgot the begining of the code, it had to be inserted into the div your code worked, i had to add curly brackets..wp-block-video.aligncenter{
    background-image: url(http://alliswell.ie/wp-content/uploads/2018/09/alliswell_ie_caring-forourwater_2018.jpg-e1536244962710.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}

Comment: Please click on uparrow so it helps other developers too. :)

Answer (score 0):

this is the answer or it worked for me
..wp-block-video.aligncenter{ background-image: url(alliswell.ie/wp-content/uploads/2018/09/…); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-size: cover; } –

thank you dineshkashera for the answer and everyone else that offered suggestions.